# Extracting content from .txt files in Laravel php framework

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am relatively new to Laravel and am building an online taxonomic guide to coral species. Each of 300 species will have a separate page which in turn will show images and have a descriptive section (1-2 paragraphs long). In the past I have handled chunks of text as an entry in a csv file which I upload to phpMyAdmin. One problem however is that a .csv file with 300 entries of 1-2 paragraphs each is very slow to scroll through in excel.

My question is: in this case is it better to have description in separate .txt files, include the .txt files in phpMyAdmin and then write a script to call each text file?

Advice on how to do this in Laravel is most appreciated!

Comment: `phpmyadmin`, do you mean a SQL database, right?

Comment: @OfirBaruch, phpMyAdmin is a data base manager for MySQL created in php

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would ditch the idea of managing this data outside of your system.

Laravel comes with a good enough authentication system, so why not create a protected page in which you can update the data directly to the database? Take a look at this [simple CRUD project](https://github.com/scotch-io/simple-laravel-crud). CRUD stands for create, replace, update, and delete.